# Is it possible to override `__name__` derived from object?

Tags: python, mocking

To get a string representation of a class name we can use `obj.__class__.__name__` is it possible to overload these methods so that I can return my string instead of the actual class name?

Comment: `__class__` and `__name__` are class properties (I believe), not functions; these are of course mutable, however, you really should not modify these values for obvious reasons. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to return some arbitrary string from the class instance? You could define your own function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's try!  (Yes, this works):

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
...
>>> obj = Foo()
>>> obj.__class__.__name__ = 'Bar'
>>> obj
<__main__.Bar object at 0x7fae8ba3af90>
>>> obj.__class__
<class '__main__.Bar'>
```

You could also have just done `Foo.__name__ = 'Bar'`, I used `obj.__class__.__name__` to be consistent with your question.

Comment: I'd rather use `Foo.__name__ = 'Bar'`, unless you have some arbitrary object and want to change the name of whatever its class is. But changing the name of some unknown class in order to have an effect on one of its instances seems *extremely* dodgy...

Comment: This does not work in python3.   The output is still "<__main__.Foo object at 0x0000021E6007F278>" ... ignoring the change to the class name.

Answer (score 5):

Yep.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__class__.__name__ = 'B'
```

But this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: So... every time we create a new object of class 'A', we rename the class to 'B'? It seems much cleaner (if you're going to rename the class) to just rename the class directly, not as a side effect of creating instances of it.

Comment: Just an example implementation.  The OP can implement based on his requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.__class__.__name__ = "Bar"
... 
>>> print Foo().__class__.__name__
Bar
```

Or you can make your own double underscore attribute.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __name__ = "Bar"
... 
>>> print Foo().__name__
Bar
```

But why would you want to do this? I don't see any possible use for this. BTW, I realize this is not the same as `__class__.__name__`, but I don't think changing `__class__.__name__` is generally a good idea.

Comment: The second version works only for instances - `Foo.__name__` will remain unchanged. Interestingly, Python3 allows properly setting `__qualname__` this way.