# Is it possible to override `__name__` derived from object in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

The example below works in Python2 but not in Python3. Is there an equivalent method for overloading the `__name__` of a class in Python3? See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769020/is-it-possible-to-override-name-derived-from-object?answertab=votes#tab-top).

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    pass
...
>>> Foo.__name__ = 'Bar'
>>> Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm actually interested in overriding the name of the particular object obj = Foo() rather than the class itself. Hence why the example was stated the way it was before your edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.3 and up use the [`__qualname__` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#definition.__qualname__) to form the class represenation string:

```
>>> class Foo: pass
...
>>> Foo.__name__ = '__name__ for Foo'
>>> Foo.__qualname__ = '__qualname__ for Foo'
>>> Foo
<class '__main__.__qualname__ for Foo'>
```

You probably want to set *both* `__name__` and `__qualname__`, but only the latter has any effect on the string output you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't answer my question as it was originally posed though (or maybe I just don't understand how?). Is it possible to override the __name__ of the object obj = Foo() as well?

Comment: @jmc: When you set attributes on `obj.__class__`, you are setting them on `Foo`. When you echo `obj` or print `repr(obj)`, then the `repr(obj.__class__)` result is used to produce the output. While you can set the `__name__` attribute on `Foo` just *fine* (so also `obj.__class__.__name__`), setting that attribute has no effect on how `repr(Foo)` and `repr(obj)` are formed.  That is determined by `__qualname__` instead.

Comment: @jmc: If that doesn't answer what you are asking them I'm really not sure why you are asking about `__name__`.